# How to delete lines from a file until a specific character? [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am trying to write a python script that goes through a file and scans it until a given word is found, then from that word it deletes all coming lines from the file until the next given word is found, as shown here:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Key-Word
Line4
Line5
Key-Word2
Line6
Line7
```

Result would be:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Key-Word2
Line6
Line7
```

So far I have managed to get it to detect the Key-Word but unsure how I can make it delete the coming lines and then continue from Key-Word2 onwards

Comment: Show the code you wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file lines then write it back except lines from the start key until the stop key, here is an example:

```py
def erase(file_name: str, start_key: str, stop_key: str):
    """
    This function will delete all line from the givin start_key
    until the stop_key. (include: start_key) (exclude: stop_key)
    """
    try: 
        # read the file lines
        with open(file_name, 'r+') as fr: 
            lines = fr.readlines()
        # write the file lines except the start_key until the stop_key
        with open(file_name, 'w+') as fw:
            # delete variable to control deletion
            delete = False
            # iterate over the file lines
            for line in lines:
                # check if the line is a start_key
                # set delete to True (start deleting)
                if line.strip('\n') == start_key:
                     delete = True
                # check if the line is a stop_key
                # set delete to False (stop deleting)
                elif line.strip('\n') == stop_key:
                     delete = False
                # write the line back based on delete value
                # if the delete setten to True this will
                # not be executed (the line will be skipped)
                if not delete: 
                    fw.write(line)
    except RuntimeError as ex: 
        print(f"erase error:\n\t{ex}")
```

Usage:

```py
erase('file.txt', 'Key-Word', 'Key-Word2')
```

file.txt (input):

```py
Line1
Line2
Line3
Key-Word
Line4
Line5
Key-Word2
Line6
Line7
```

after running the function:

```py
Line1
Line2
Line3
Key-Word2
Line6
Line7
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is amazing, it has helped me a lot to understand how file handling works and what I should be doing, you have really given me the kickstart needed. Thank you!

Comment: That is my pleasure, if you want to know more about file IO in python, take a look at this article https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation

Comment: Thank you again, I’m quite new to Python so this is definitely something useful - on to new projects now! Can’t wait to play around more with files

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should open the file twice. Once to read the lines and once to write. If for some reason you got an error in your forloop trying to do both reading and writing at once, you may end up with a partially affected file.

You need to be careful to strip the white space in between lines as the characters "\n" will get appended to your string.

```
keyword_found = False
with open("line_file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("line_file.txt", "w") as f:
    while (lines):
        line = lines.pop(0).strip("\n")
        if line == 'you':
            keyword_found = True
        if line == 'friend':
            keyword_found = False
        if not keyword_found:
            f.write(line + "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you very much this has given me a good starting point on the logic I should follow!